# error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token|

Tags: c

sorry for bothering you with such basic question but I am trying to learn C (and later C++) programming but I can not get compiler to compile so while struggling to get to understand how to the IDEs work (I tried both Code Blocks and CodeLite to get this code to work) then I keep getting the same errors . 
IDE keep showing this problem at first opening brace which I do not  understand as the braces looks placed correctly to me (?).

I have also tried moving the main function to above the addtwo function but it doesn't seem to make any difference .

Program :

```
/* program to add two numbers and return result */
#include <stdio.h>

/* This function adds two numbers */

int addtwo( int x , int y );

{
    int result;
    int result = x+y ;
    return (result)
}

int main()
{
    int sum ;
    sum=addtwo(25,49);
    printf("25 + 49 = %d \n",sum);
    getchar();
    return sum;
}
```

Compiler output :

```
||=== Build: Debug in CB Test 01 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

C:\Users\User\Documents\CodeBlocks files\CB Test 01\main.c|8|error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token|

||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: You have an extra semi colon in `int addtwo(int x, int y);`, remove it. You will have another error, because you redeclare `result` in `addtwo`, either remove the second type specifier, or remove the first declaration. Or, `return x + y;` and that's all.

Comment: Also you are missing a semicolon after `return (result)`.

Comment: `return` is not a function. Don't use parenteses for its expression, they can shadow syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for all your help , very much appreciated.  It is very difficult to understand compiler errors at my level of C programming  knowledge since they errors produced are not shown where problems is.   I obviously has got a lot to learn also in terms of proof reading the code according to the book that I use.  I will try to do better in the future.   As for solution it was a group effort that did it here for me though Al Asimi nailed it through two different posts/answers.   Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you all.P.S.  As for the "down rating" of my question then I'd like to add that I had used hours to try to solve problem prior to asking. But when aim is trying to gain a basic understanding C programming then it ought to be understandable if one puts a semi colon or a parenthesis where it should not be. I am trying to make a transition from old home computer language to C and it is quite different+difficult when not understanding if problem is IDE or code or if one screwed up installing IDE,compiler or whatever To understand you need to be a beginner in using the IDEs and Compilers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No semicolon after `(result)` in addtwo function. Also the parentheses `()` are not necessary.
2. Extra semicolon in,

   ```
   int addtwo( int x , int y );
   /*                         ^ here */
   {
       int result;
       int result = x+y ;
       return (result)
   }
   ```

Comment: `()` are not braces according to the standard.

Comment: Thank you very much , that helped a lot.   As you (?) wrote in another remark / post above then I also had to remove the int result as to not re-declare  I did not understand that what I did was a double declaration .  I thought that I firstly declared the result variable and then afterwards just added values to it.  I obviously need to try to get a better grasp of what exactly declarations cover as subject.  Thank you for your help.